# Read resource from outside of web content folder

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

I have write a context.xml in my project application folder to read the resources from outside of the application folder

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context reloadable="true">
 <Resources>
   `<PreResources  base="C:/test"` className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet" webAppMount="/application" />


 </Resources>



 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"  allow=".*" />

</Context>
```

My question is is it possible set a enviorment variable in base entity of PreResources tag.
That means something like the below example

```
<PreResources  base="${MYPATH}" className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet" webAppMount="/application" />`
```